# Scheme Zip Function

Tags: list, scheme, zipper

I need to write a function in Scheme that acts as a zipper - meaning it takes two lists and creates a 'zipper' out of the two lists such that

```
(zip '(a b c) '(1 2 3)) => ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))
```

Furthermore it takes each element in the nth position and pairs them together.

I'm fairly new to Scheme, so any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my [Standard Prelude](http://programmingpraxis.com/standard-prelude): `(define (zip . xss) (apply map list xss))`